# Beveled faces not showing

Tags: bevel

I'm inexperienced with 3D modeling and have tried to solve this issue to no luck.  I have a cube with beveled edges that I am trying to use in a game but unfortunately when I export the beveled edges don't show.[image]

Comment: I have turned on back face culling to make sure the faces are pointed the right direction

Comment: that's a weird issue, are your normals correct?

Comment: @Millard ill be honest, I dont know what that means

Comment: ok, your normals are the direction your faces are pointing, so if you notice that their are faces on the outside of your mesh that are darker than the others, it can mean that your normals are out of wack.  this is especially important for game engines, as incorrect normals can mean faces disappear.  if your having problems with normals, just select all your normals and press **ctrl + n.**  this should fix it.  I hope i was clear on this, :)

Comment: Oh okay, awesome yeah that was pretty straight forward I'll give it a try!

Comment: It could also be that you need to apply the modifier before you export.